# Dynamically Creating an Excel Userform using C# and adding buttons to it

Tags: c#, excel, vba, automation

I am putting together a small C# application to mimic the development of an Excel VBA project I have been working on. The idea is that I can code in C# and then it will build the relevant excel document and add all of the vba code for me. The bit that I am a little stuck on at the moment is adding buttons to a userform that I have created dynamically.

```
var selectedWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilename);      
var userForm = selectedWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_MSForm);
    userForm.Name = "form1Mod";
    userForm.Properties.Item("Caption").Value = "Setting this up";
```

In the above code I am able to add a Userform and modify it's caption however I can't see anyway of adding controls. it could be me just missing something silly.

I do have access to:

```
 userForm.Collection.Add
```

however this doesn't give me the ability to add anything other than

```
vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_MSForm
```

I've had a google around and nothing is jumping out at me. I know it can be done in VBA but I just can't fathom how to achieve the same in C#

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you assume that, since it can be done in VBA, it must be possible with C#?  ...and for that matter, why not do it with VBA instead; the language that was *meant* for Excel?  ...You could always initiate the completed VBA from C# if you needed to for some reason, by simply programmatically opening the file (and have a Startup form auto-run the code)...

Comment: i agree with ashleedawg, why do it in c#? you can just make a template form in a template excel file and copy that form into every new excel file that you generate with c#

Comment: I make the assumption based on the fact that VSTO was built in order to allow .net developers to build office applications. Building this in C# is just a small part of a bigger solution I am trying to build up, using C# makes it so much easier for version control and for distribution of updates. There is also the added stability of not having to store as much data in Excel which can be flaky at times. I agree that VBA was built for office, however a lot of what I do pushes excel to it's limits. As a developer it's my job to think outside the box.